# Why is logrotate causing Apache to seg fault each time?

Tags: apache-2.4, logrotate, segmentation-fault

Every time `logrotate` runs  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) experiences a seg fault and does not restart:

```
[Wed Sep 10 06:35:54.266018 2014] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20599:tid 140630283466624] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Sep 10 06:35:54.885118 2014] [core:notice] [pid 20599] AH00060: seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
```

My apache logrotate script looks like:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
    endscript
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi; \
    endscript
}

/srv/apache/log/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
    endscript
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi; \
    endscript
}
```

I keep the default logs in `/var/log/apache2`, but I keep vhost specific logs (for the three different vhosts hosted on this server) in the `/srv/apache/log` directory (e.g. `mysite1_error.log`, `mysite1_access.log`, `mysite2_error.log`, `mysite2_access.log`....).

The relevant parts of `/etc/apache2/apache.conf`:

```
#/etc/apache2/apache.conf
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel trace8   # I set to try and get more info about this problem.
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

where `export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX`. In my vhost conf files, such as 
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite1.conf` I have:

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite1.conf
LogLevel debug
ErrorLog  /srv/apache/log/mysite1_error.log
CustomLog /srv/apache/log/mysite2_access.log combined
```

and similar for the other sites.

Anyone know why logrotate is causing this crash?

**One more thing:**

Manually forcing the logrotate as root:

```
logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
```

does not cause the seg fault, but I know it's logrotate as I've tried playing with the times (weekly, daily) and the seg fault always occurs exactly as the logs are being rotated only.

**How to reproduce on demand**

```
# Set a crontab to run each minute (simulating cron.daily run of logrotate)
crontab -e
*/1 * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/apache2 > /home/myuser/logrotate.log 2>&1
```

**Finally**

If I comment out the `/srv/apache/log/*.log` rotation block in `/etc/logrotate.d/apache` the seg fault does not occur either.

Comment: Form the error message it looks like `/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful` is the offender (in theory scripts within /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate are also candidates). Can you confirm by running `/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful` manually?
Is there any more hints when this happens in Apache's global errorlog (or the global syslog), maybe when you increase the LogLevel not only within <VirtualHost> but globally?

Comment: `/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful` manually at cmd line causes no problems (Also note that this line was originally `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null` but after getting the seg fault, I changed to `apachectl` on advice I read online, obviously it did not fix things). The LogLevel is already at the highest possible globally, `trace8` set in the `apache.conf` file.

Comment: And just to rule it out: `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate` does not exist.

Comment: This is usually caused by a module not shutting down properly. Are you using any exotic modules? Anything added recently? 3rd-party modules? Try disabling them.

Comment: So `/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful` is causing a segfault when issued by logrotate, but not when issued manually? Odd

Comment: @NilsToedtmann Even more specific in fact. A manual run of logrotate causes no isses (`logrotate -f -v /etc/logrotate.d/apache2`) but when ran by cron the segfault occurs. I'm going to update my OP with some further findings.

Comment: @gtirloni `apachectl -M` shows my loaded modules as http://paste.ubuntu.com/8309365/

Comment: Can you try starting Apache through strace so you capture exactly where it's segfaulting? Stop it completely then run `strace -ff -o trace.log -r apachectl start` and attempt the graceful shutdown that will segfault it.

Comment: It's easier to reproduce if you create a /etc/cron.d/logrotate-test with `*/1 *    * * *   root   /usr/sbin/logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/apache2 > /home/myuser/logrotate.log 2>&1`

Comment: @NilsToedtmann Yes good point, I'll update my post. From my experiments so far it seems that if I just change the logrotate script to be a single block, i.e. `/var/log/apache2/*.log, /srv/apache/logs/*.log {....}` I don't get the segfault. So maybe it was just the two blocks were causing a second restart attempt during the first restart...

Comment: Interesting.  On my system `apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful &` doesn't segfault. That's 4 simultaneous graceful restarts. You get the same?

Comment: (removed a stupid thought)

Comment: @NilsToedtmann If I enter `apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful &` my system DOES segfault! Strange, I wonder why mine does and yours does not. Oh well, I guess that is mystery solved....If anyone wants to add an answer to this effect I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: @fpghost you might want to add the answer yourself (that there seems to be a bad module preventing the reload, and basically forces you to stop/start apache.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that if I just change the logrotate script to be a single block, i.e. `/var/log/apache2/*.log, /srv/apache/logs/*.log {....}` I don't get the segfault. So it was just the two blocks were causing a second restart attempt during the first restart...

If I enter `apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful & apache2ctl graceful &` on the cmd line my system DOES segfault, which seems to confirm

Comment: I have this exact problem, but only one block in my logrotate script to begin with. Any ideas?